# Which of the following reactions doesn't represent an oxidation-reduction

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, oxidation-state, reduction-potential

> Which of the following reactions doesn't represent an oxidation-reduction?
>
> $$
>   \begin{align*}
>     \ce{2 P + 5 HClO + 3 H2O &-> 2 H3PO4 + 5 HCl} \\
>     \ce{Zn + 2 HCl &-> ZnCl2 + H2} \\
>     \ce{Mg + CuSO4 &-> MgSO4 + Cu} \\
>     \ce{NaOH + HNO3 &-> NaNO3 + H2O}
>   \end{align*}
> $$

I want to find which of those reactions is not an oxidation-reduction reaction, but I'm not sure how to do this and how to find the oxidation numbers, should I memorize them?

Is there some rules like when bases and acids react this can't be an oxidation-reduction reaction — **the last reaction implies this** — so I can know if the reaction is an oxidation-reduction reaction or not when I look at it without searching for every oxidation number?

Comment: Only the last one doesn't. This case can be solved trivially without memorizing anything as in the first three reactions an element is a reactant, and the fourth reaction is a neutralization reaction. But in general, yes, you need to memorize typical oxidation numbers of elements and charges of common anions and cations.

Comment: @andselisk so if there is an element in the reactants, does this means that it must by an oxidation-reduction reaction?

Comment: If there is an element in the reactants and it is not an element in the products then yes, oxidation/reduction has occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is an element in the reactants and it is not an element in the products then yes, oxidation or reduction has occurred.
Acid-base reactions are pretty much non-redox reactions. But it is always handy to learn the oxidations numbers.
Extra sources
[Do non-redox reactions exist?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18492/do-non-redox-reactions-exist)

Comment: "Well acid-base reactions are pretty much non-redox reactions".  
Do you mean that **almost** all acid-base reactions are non-redox or are you emphasizing that all acid-base reactions are non-redox reactions ?

Comment: Well if you mean by acids, the species which give H+ ion in solution and by base, thes species which give OH- ion in solution, yes. I haven't known anything yet. However, it doesnot account for lewis base and lewis acids.

Comment: And i would add up to @Waylander. "Vice-versa"

Comment: I have just suggested an edit to contain both to accept it as an answer.